# NameError: name " " is not defined

Tags: python, data-analysis, nameerror

New to python programming,While I was analysing spotify Datasets I got this error.

What I was doing was Plot a Line Graph to Show the Duration of the Songs for Each Year.

Any idea how do i fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggriu.png)

sns.displot(years,discrete=True,aspect=2,heights=5,kind="hist").set(title="Number of songs per year")

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12628\3904715389.py in 
----> 1 sns.displot(years,discrete=True,aspect=2,heights=5,kind="hist").set(title="Number of songs per year")

NameError: name 'years' is not defined

This is the Sample spotify datasets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzDLE.png)

I expecting solution for the Error.

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: There is no variable called years.

Comment: How to add variables?

Answer (score 0):

the data `years` which you are trying to visualize through distplot may not be defined. Make sure to store in the variable first like , years = `Your_Sample_spotify_data["year"]` and than you can defined it as the first argument of  distplot().

Comment: Do I have to declare variable from Jupyter notebook?

Comment: yes, make a new cell above of `sns.distplot()` code, and assign all the years details from  dataframe to variable name `years`. Or else in the same code, in place of giving `years` as a parameter, you can give `your_Sample_spotify_data["years"]`. But make sure years column  exist in your dataframe.